# How can I get data for one field from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `ContentID` in a table that identifies content that exists in other tables. For example, it could refer to a `pageID`, `productID`, etc. My plan is to use that to pull through other information I need, such as a page name or product name. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT TL.ID, TL.TableName, TL.FileName, TL.ContentID, p.PageName AS Content
FROM TranslationLog TL
LEFT JOIN Pages P ON TL.ContentID = P.PageID
LEFT JOIN Categories C ON TL.ContentID = C.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN ProductDescriptions PD ON TL.ContentID = PD.SKU
```

The idea is for each row, I want to get the data for the specified content using the `TableName` and `ContentID` fields. Currently, I'm able to get `PageName` by selecting `p.PageName AS Content`. However, I'd like to do this for each of the tables; if the row corresponds to the pages table, then query that table - same for categories and product descriptions. I also need it to have the alias *"Content"*, regardless of which field from another table we're using, such as `PageName` or `ProductName`.

Is it possible to do this?

EDIT:

The solution posted by rd_nielsen was almost perfect, but it turned out there was actually a bit of overlap with the `ContentID`. Here's what I ended up with to fix it:

```
SELECT TL.ID, TL.TableName, TL.FileName, TL.ContentID, coalesce(P.PageName, C.CategoryName, PD.ProductName)
FROM TranslationLog TL
LEFT JOIN Pages P ON TL.ContentID = P.PageID AND TL.TableName = 'Pages'
LEFT JOIN Categories C ON TL.ContentID = C.CategoryID AND TL.TableName = 'Categories'
LEFT JOIN ProductDescriptions PD ON TL.ContentID = PD.SKU AND TL.TableName = 'Products'
```

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values of `TranslationLog.ContentID` can appear in only one of the related tables, then you can coalesce the values from those tables:

```
SELECT 
    TL.ID, 
    TL.TableName, 
    TL.FileName, 
    TL.ContentID, 
    coalesce(p.PageName, C.CategoryName, PD.ProductName) AS Content
FROM
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah, ContentID can only appear in one of the tables - this is perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use cross-apply. For example:

```
select 
    T.* 
from 
    table_stored_data u
cross apply dbo.created_function(u.contentid,u.tablename,u.search_column) T
```

You need to write a function for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `concat` function:

```
select concat(p.PageName, C.CategoryName, PD.ProductName) AS Content from ...
```